# Weird positioning behaviour

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've been toying around a bit with positioning (relative and absolute) and i ran into a weird problem.

**HTML:**

```
​<div class="one">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt sem ac      lacus varius ullamcorper. Sed sed tincidunt lorem. Integer volutpat mauris eu elit condimentum vehicula. Vestibulum vitae urna id risus ornare porta. Praesent quis tortor nunc. Donec ut aliquam orci. Mauris cursus quam mauris. Aliquam iaculis, augue malesuada egestas blandit, erat lectus vestibulum magna, sed pharetra arcu orci nec ligula. Proin non sem dui. Integer viverra viverra est sit amet fermentum. Pellentesque egestas tristique eros vel interdum. Nam vel neque odio, et mollis nulla. Vestibulum fermentum augue vel justo ullamcorper molestie. Sed eget enim urna, a elementum mi. Aenean ornare viverra dictum.

 </p>
<div class="inner"></div>

</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.one{
    position: relative;   
}
.one p{
    margin-top: 60px;          
}
.inner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;   
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}​
```

As you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqpfb), I apply margin to the `<p>` tag, but it pushes the entire wrapping div and thus affecting the positioned element as well.

Is that the way it should behave or am i missing something?

Comment: your margin is working as expected. it is taking margin-top:60px for the main div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `overflow: auto;` on your .one element.

Comment: This is a (weird) common problem. You can find some info here http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow, and a simple search on google will give you a lot of articles on the subject

Answer (score 1):

`Overflow:auto` works for this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DMrNe/1/)**

Reason: Here is explanation for this http://www.brunildo.org/test/OverflowR.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll upvote your answer but i'll give it to Chuck since he was the first one :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply padding-top to the containing div instead of margin-top to the

element.

Comment: I know this is a solution that will work, my question is why the margin doesn't work as expected?

Comment: That's the way it works with inline elements. To change this behaviour, set display:inline-block to the <p> element, but you'll lose compatibility with older browsers (eg. IE6)

Answer (score 0):

`Div` with `class="one"` have this css rule

`position:relative`

that pushes all its content down.

Remember that once you write `position:absolute`, this `absolute` will refer to its "container".
If you **remove** the *relative positioning* from `one` and `one p` you'll obtain wat you want

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6TKn9/)**

Comment: yes, but in that case it is positioned relative to the body, which is usually not the wanted behaviour.

Comment: @ftom2 No, not relative to the body. Relative to its container that is, in this case, in turn relative to the body. So for transition, is relative to the body....

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position is applied to the parent relative. If you want the absolute positioned div to be at the top of the page, don't use relative at `one` or `one p`.

Is this what you were looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/DYBpg/